# chartist.js animation on update/change data

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

Is there any way to add animation/transition on update/change data using the Chartist.js?

I'm trying now to do it through the draw event but it's seems hardly possible for me.

Answer (score 1):

seems there is no way you can do it in chartist, and there are no updates on this https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/607

You can switch to charts.js, which is way better, but much bigger (+300kb in minified state). 
Examples https://admin.vuebulma.com/#/charts/chartjs